# Incorrect UITextfield is being edited

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I just finished a tutorial on making my own keypad.  So I took that knowledge and made a real simple App that adds two numbers with my own keypad.  It is just two numbers.  But when I tap on one textfield, the other textfield gets edited!  I have enclosed my code, any help will be much appreciated.  And thanks to @spacious for all previous help.

```
#import "KeyPad2ViewController.h"

@interface KeyPad2ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsEnteringANumber;
@end

@implementation KeyPad2ViewController
@synthesize numberOne;
@synthesize numberTwo;
@synthesize result;
@synthesize keyPad;
@synthesize userIsEnteringANumber;
@synthesize currentTextField;


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([numberOne isFirstResponder]) 
{
    self.currentTextField = self.numberOne;
    self.userIsEnteringANumber = NO;
}
else if ([numberTwo isFirstResponder])
{
    self.currentTextField = self.numberTwo;
    self.userIsEnteringANumber = NO;
}
return YES;

}    

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[numberOne setInputView:keyPad];
[numberTwo setInputView:keyPad];
numberOne.delegate = self;
numberTwo.delegate = self;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setNumberOne:nil];
[self setNumberTwo:nil];
[self setResult:nil];
[self setKeyPad:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
NSString *button = [sender currentTitle];
NSRange decimalpoint = [self.currentTextField.text rangeOfString:@"."];
if (self.userIsEnteringANumber)
{
    if ([button isEqualToString:@"."] && decimalpoint.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        self.currentTextField.text = self.currentTextField.text;
    }else 
        self.currentTextField.text = [self.currentTextField.text stringByAppendingString:button];
}else 
{
    self.currentTextField.text = button;
    self.userIsEnteringANumber = YES;
}
}

- (IBAction)backspacePressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
if (self.userIsEnteringANumber)
{
    int positionOfDigitBeforeLastOne = self.currentTextField.text.length -1;
    if (self.currentTextField.text.length > 0)
    {
        self.currentTextField.text = [self.currentTextField.text substringToIndex:positionOfDigitBeforeLastOne];
    }
    if (self.currentTextField.text.length == 0)
        self.currentTextField.text = @"";
}
}

- (IBAction)clearPressed:(id)sender 
{
currentTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
[self hideKeyPad];
}

- (IBAction)signPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
NSString *negativeNumber = @"-";
NSString *firstCharInDisplay = @"";
if (self.userIsEnteringANumber)
{
    firstCharInDisplay = [self.currentTextField.text substringToIndex:1];
    if ([firstCharInDisplay isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        self.currentTextField.text = [self.currentTextField.text substringFromIndex:1];
    }else {
        negativeNumber = [negativeNumber stringByAppendingString:self.currentTextField.text];
        self.currentTextField.text = negativeNumber;
    }
}
}

- (IBAction)add:(UIButton *)sender 
{
float a = [[numberOne text] floatValue];
float b = [[numberTwo text] floatValue];

float c = a + b;

[result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", c]];
}

- (void)showKeyPad
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
CGRect keypadview = CGRectMake(0, 270, 320, 190); // puts keyboard on screen
keyPad.frame = keypadview;
keyPad.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)hideKeyPad
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
CGRect keypadview = CGRectMake(0, 640, 320, 190);  // puts keyboard off screen
keyPad.frame = keypadview;
keyPad.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

and my .h file is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KeyPad2ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *result;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *keyPad;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *currentTextField;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)backspacePressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)clearPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)enterPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)octopusPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)signPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)add:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

Thanks to any and all help.  This site is really the best!!

Comment: You sure you have everything connected correctly?

Comment: @Hot Licks, Yeah, I even went back to make sure the numberOne text field was connected to the numberOne in the .h file, same with the numberTwo variable.  Any other ideas about what to make sure is connected correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is being called at the time after the first responder has been set, or just before the first responder is set?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I put in an NSLog, when I enter the text field for the first time, textFieldShouldBeginEditing is not called.  When I click on text field two (numberTwo) then numberOne becomes first responder.  If I click on numberOne, numberTwo becomes first responder.  Do you know how to change this?  I read the Apple docs on the methods, and I didn't see anything that would help me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method is called, the first responder has not been set to the correct field yet. Replace the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` with `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` to fix this problem.

Comment: I changed the code to the following: `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([numberOne isFirstResponder]) 
    {
        self.currentTextField = self.numberOne;
        self.userIsEnteringANumber = NO;
    }
    else if ([numberTwo isFirstResponder])
    {
        self.currentTextField = self.numberTwo;
        self.userIsEnteringANumber = NO;
    }
}` I also changed the enterPressed method to resignFirstResponder so that the keyboard will pop up again. Thanks for everyone's help with this.